# Python Basic If Statement

Tags: python, function, if-statement

```
def main_loop():

  print "where are you from?"
  loc = raw_input()

  print "so your from " + loc + "?"
  ans = raw_input()


def isittrue():
  if ans == "yes":
    print "We all love " + loc
  else:
    print "Where did you say you were from again?"


main_loop()    
isittrue()
```

Im trying to create a script that will prompt the user for their location, ask them to confirm the location, if the location is confirmed to then display a message, otherwise start the script again.

However keep getting the following error:
NameError: name 'ans' is not defined on line 18 in main.py

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ans` is available only in `main_loop`'s scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your code and this works :

```
def main_loop():

  print ("where are you from?")
  loc = input()

  print ("so your from " + loc + "?")
  ans = input()

  isittrue(ans,loc)


def isittrue(ans,loc):
  if ans == "yes":
    print ("We all love " , loc)
  else:
    print ("Where did you say you were from again?")


main_loop()
```

You can use only main_loop() for calling and use isittrue() in main_loop, passing the two strings .Also it's better to use input() , raw_input() "is outdate"

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is **scope**. Variable names are local to the function they are called to.

If you reference `ans` inside `isittrue()`, Python - and most languages, for that matter - have no idea you're referencing a variable in another function. They only have access to variables in the enclosing scope, in this case the global scope.

The easiest way to do it is to move `isittrue` *inside* `mainloop()` so that the enclosing scope becomes that of `mainloop()` and `isittrue()` now has access to the variables defined in `mainloop`.

```
def main_loop():

    print "where are you from?"
    loc = raw_input()

    print "so your from " + loc + "?"
    ans = raw_input()


    def isittrue():
        if ans == "yes":
            print "We all love " + loc
        else:
            print "Where did you say you were from again?"

    isittrue()


main_loop()
```

Comment: Decided to go with this.

Comment: def main_loop():

     print "where are you from?"

     loc = raw_input()

     print "so your from " + loc + "?"
 
     ans = raw_input()
 

     def isittrue():
    
      if ans == "yes":
       print "We all love " + loc
      else:

          print "Whatt?"
 
         main_loop()
   
    
     isittrue()



    main_loop()

Answer (score 1):

your `ans` variable is local to function main_loop(), so its not acessible within `isittrue` function

you can make ans variable global by adding below into top of `main_loop` function, then ans will be acessible from `isittrue` function.
However, its not so recommended to using global as global variables are evil

```
def main_loop():
    global ans, loc
    print "where are you from?"
    loc = raw_input()

    print "so your from " + loc + "?"
    ans = raw_input()
```

or better way is to use `return` to return `ans` from `main_loop` function

```
def main_loop():
    global ans
    print "where are you from?"
    loc = raw_input()

    print "so your from " + loc + "?"
    ans = raw_input()
    return ans, loc

def isittrue(ans, loc):
    if ans == "yes":
        print "We all love " + loc
    else:
        print "Where did you say you were from again?"

ans, loc = main_loop()    
isittrue(ans,loc)
```

Comment: I would recommend adding a caveat that using global variables are considered an anti-pattern for the most part.